# What is the difference between this two queries

Tags: postgresql, jpql

I am using JPQL to get data from my PostgresSQL dataBase, my query compare two character varying, (I am using a StringBuilder to create a query)   it will look like this

**The StringBuilder**

```
StringBuilder queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("SELECT o FROM entity AS o WHERE 1 = 1 ");
```

**The Condition : Solution 1**

```
queryStringBuilder.append(" AND o.num >= CONCAT(SUBSTRING(o.num,1,LENGTH(o.num) - LENGTH(:numStart)),:numStart)")
```

and it return this error

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>
> ERREUR: l'argument de AND doit être de type booléen, et non du type text
>     Position : 460
>   Error Code: 0

after hard time working and trying other queries i have done this solution

**The Condition : Solution 2**

```
queryStringBuilder.append(" AND SUBSTRING(o.num , LENGTH(o.num) - 1 ,  LENGTH(:numStart) )  >=  :numStart ")
```

and with the second query it's working fine.

***First query example***

`o.num = 123456789` and `numStart = 98` it will compare `123456789` with `123456798` (in this case it will return False)

***Second query example***

`o.num = 123456789` and `numStart = 98` it will compare `89` with `98` (in this case it will return also False)

my question is : What is the difference between this two queries, and how to make the first one work.

Comment: can you add the whole query. `The AND argument must be Boolean, not text type Position` where are other comparison parts from your query.

Comment: @lightsouls I've edited my question , it's true there is other conditions but i am sure this is the problem (because when i remove this condition every thing work nice)